# How to version vagrant files for a specific project

Tags: git, vagrant

I have been trying to work out a good way of versioning my vagrant files which are specific to a project. After lots of searching on the Internet for quite some time I've not come up with anything.

So I thought I'd ask here, how do people version their vagrant files which are for a specific project? Put them all in the same repository? Completely separate git repositories for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put it in the same git repo as my project files. The idea is that everyone in the same team shares the same environment, so for this we all share the same Vagrant file

The benefits are :

- We all use the same base box (if new version is needed, we make sure it is available for others otherwise `vagrant up`will fail)
- Everyone is doing the same provisioning (we're using puppet but it can really be anything)

Comment: Seems as though no  one does it any other way, I'll give this a go on my new project. Don't know why I just always had this feeling they should be kept separate to the project main files but tied together somehow. Thanks for the reply.